# WebRTC support on BlackBerry 10

Tags: android-ndk, blackberry-10, webrtc

Are there WebRTC libraries ported to BlackBerry? If not, is it possible to port Android NDK code to BB10 project?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) is completely free for both paid and unpaid apps.

Currently, BlackBerry is interested in delivering support for WebRTC and are researching/investigating on the technology.  However, no dates or release schedules have been announced at the moment.

Depending on the APIs being used in the Android app. it may or may not be possible to [port Android NDK](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/bb10/porting_from_android_ndk.html) code to BlackBerry10.

Though the Android Runtime would not support WebRTC projects, BlackBerry10 OS is built on QNX, which is a fully compliant POSIX system. 
The QNX compiler, QCC, has a GCC-compliant mode to easily port over existing code.